# Windows 11 system randomly cannot start one of the network interfaces when Omron PLC and Gocator camera is connected

Tags: networking, windows-11, ethernet, connection, windows-networking

The problem is the PC (Nuvo-9160GC running Windows 11) connects to an Omron PLC via Ethernet, and at the same time to a Gocator camera via another Ethernet port.

The IP addresses are correctly configured according to the necessary range Everything works fine, but there are times when we start the Windows 11 system it does not start one of the interfaces.

To solve it, we can restart Windows and then it will detect it correctly.

How can this be solved?

Comment: What does the Event Viewer have to say regarding this? It should have records of it trying to start the network hardware and the results.

Comment: These two devices are part of the same subnet?